# Is there a way to block access to my e-mail in my iPod Touch, so I can lend it?

Tags: ipod-touch, applications, mail.app, security

I would like to lend my iPod Touch 4 sometimes, but I would like to block access to my e-mails (as well as Facebook), is there a way?

Comment: Can you set your email accounts so that the password must be given in order to access them from the iPod?  Maybe in Preferences, insert dummy passwords.  Then after you get the phone back, insert the real passwords.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Delete your mail account and log out of facebook?

Answer (score 1):

there is no way to "hide" your email account or facebook settings with the default OS (i dont know about jailbroken)

the only way you can cover this is as Lyken says, remove the email account from your phone and logout from facebook

what you could do, is restore the ipod to factory default (after syncing to make a backup) lend the device, then when you get it back, you could restore the phone again this time from your saved backup from before

Answer (score 1):

If you jailbreak it you can use Lockdown Pro. I locked all my apps except games which my little brother uses all the time. It's pretty handy.

Answer (score 1):

[My Secret Folder](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/my-secret-folder/id456939837?mt=8) lets you drag apps into it and add a password to opening the folder.

Put the FB and Mail app in there.

Comment: Are you using this together with Mail? Does this also prevent mails from showing up on the Search/Spotlight screen?

Comment: No mail will come up in the spotlight search. However you will need to actually search for the title or sender of the email for it to appear.